# Continuity of derivative of a given function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f(x)= \tan(x), \forall x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=x, \forall x\not\in\mathbb Q$. This is obvious that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and I guess $f'(0)$ exists and it's equal to $1$. But is derivative of $f$ continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: Since the derivative of tanx and x both are equal to 1 at 0, then it is continuous over 0, but this can't be applied over a domain.

Answer (score 1):

This function is not differentiable in any interval $(-r,r)$ around $0$ so the question of continuity does not arise.